# RequireJS - loading non-script files using CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, requirejs

I have a large client-side project written in AngularJS that uses RequireJS for async module loading.

Many of my Angular directives use their own HTML and CSS.
For example:

```
define(function (require) {
    require('css!path/to/directive-name.css');
    app.directive('directive-name', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: require('text!path/to/directive-name.html'),
            controller: function ($scope) {
                // code 
            }
        };
    });
});
```

These days I'm working on making my application work with a CDN service.
So for all the JavaScript files I have changed the `require.config.js` file to:

```
paths: {
        app: [
            '//cdn.domain.net/path/to/main',
            'main'
        ],
}
```

But there are lots of directives that are being loaded at the startup page of my application, and for each of them there are two files (CSS, HTML) that are loaded from my origin server and not from the CDN.

In what way could I modify the `require.config.js` file to make the browser fetch the htmls, css's from the CDN server?

Is there an option that for **every** file that's being requir'ed - the browser will fetch it from the CDN and fallback to my origin server in case of CDN failure **although not explicitly mentioned in `require.config.js`**?

Answer (score 0):

There's [path fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks). You'll have to assign an ID to your dependency, and define that ID to have a path mapping with CDN first, local second. Unfortunately, you'll have to do this for each of your dependencies.

On the other hand, consider using RequireJS optimizer to bundle your app into one file or a bunch of them, and CDN those files instead. That way, you don't have to ID each and every one of your dependencies.

Comment: I do bundle all the files using RequireJS optimizer, but that does not take the css and html templates and inserts them into the bundled file.

What can I do in order to save those XHR calls for fetching these files?

Comment: @johni As far as I know, you will still need to use a config file even when using the bundle. If I remember correctly, I used the same config file in development for production, which has those mappings. Load RequireJS, then the config, then the bundle.

Comment: That's also true for my case, I use the same config file. Yet I don't see how can I make requirejs fetch relative-path-files from the pre-configured cdn.
I can't name an ID to 100+ directives and add them to the config file, that's insane.

I was hoping there's another way